# Upload a file in NodeJs with Multer and change name if the file already exists

Tags: node.js, multer

I need to upload a file from my client to a Node server (I use Multer to perform this task).

The requirement is that if a file with the same name already exists on the server I need to change the name of the new file. I use Node fs.stat to check for the existence of a file with the same name.

I must be doing something wrong since fs.stat always tells me that there is no file with the same name when in fact it is there (I end up overwriting the old file with the new one).

Here is the code.

```
       var imagesDirectory = 'images';
        var imageDir = '/' + imagesDirectory + '/';
        var storageDisk = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: imagesDirectory,
            filename: function (req, file, callback) {
                let uploadedFileName;
                fs.stat(imageDir + file.originalname, function(err, stat) {
                    if (err==null) {
                        uploadedFileName = Date.now() + '.' + file.originalname;
                    } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
                        uploadedFileName = file.originalname;
                    } else {
                        console.log('Some other error: ', err.code);
                    }
                    callback(null, uploadedFileName)
                });
            }
        })
        var uploadImage = multer({ storage: storageDisk, limits: {fileSize: 1000000, files:1}, }).single('imageFile');
        router.post('/image', function(req, res) {
            uploadImage(req, res, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    // An error occurred when uploading
                    console.log(err);
                }
// do something to prepare the response and send it back to the client
prepareResponseAndSendItBack(req.file.filename, imageDir, res, err);
            })
        })
```

Comment: You do realize you're passing `/images/...` to `fs.stat()` right? That path is an absolute path on your file system, it is not a url path that is relative to your public directory. Are you sure that directory really exists on the root of your file system (alongside the likes of `/usr`, `/lib`, etc.)?

Comment: Thx. I was not realizing. After removing the first '/' everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `fs.exists` is more suitable for that task.

```
fs.exists(imageDir + file.originalname, function(exists) {
    let uploadedFileName;
    if (exists) {
        uploadedFileName = Date.now() + '.' + file.originalname;
    } else {
        uploadedFileName = file.originalname;
    } 
    callback(null, uploadedFileName)
});
```

Also make sure that you pass the fullpath (or a relative one to the current file) of the file

Comment: Actually `fs.stat()` is a better solution for most cases since you typically also would want to know if the path *does* exist, whether it is a file or a directory or something else.

Comment: @mscdex It seems that `fs.exists` became deprecated https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback since it can introduce a race condition. So yes it is better to avoid it. However, I don't get your point.  `fs.exists` works for both files and directories.

Comment: Let's say you were using `fs.exists()` to check if a file exists before reading from it (for some silly reason). If the path you pass in is actually a directory, you won't know because `fs.exists()` will just return `true`. Then you go to read from it (e.g. via `fs.open()`) and you end up getting an error because it's a directory and not a file. So by using `fs.stat()` you're testing for existence and *at the same time* you can also tell whether it's a directory, normal file, a device, etc.