# Same Image not uploading in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to upload an image using express but I am facing two problems, first, whenever I upload the same image again it's not getting uploaded and secondly after uploading any single image a file with image also uploading. Here is my code.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var uploads = multer({dest: './images'});
app.post('/uploading', uploads.single("file"), function (req, res) {

   var file = __dirname +"/images" + "/" + req.file.originalname;

   fs.readFile( req.file.path, function (err, data) { 
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err,data) {
         if( err ){
              console.error( err );
              response = {
                   message: 'Sorry, file couldn\'t be uploaded.',
                   filename: req.file.originalname
              };
         }else{
               response = {
                   message: 'File uploaded successfully',
                   filename: req.file.originalname
              };
          }
          res.end( JSON.stringify( response ) );
       });
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `uploads.single("file")` middleware **Will handle the file upload**. You don't have to specifically `fs.read` and `fs.write` the file.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var uploads = multer({dest: './images'});
app.post('/uploading', uploads.single("file"), function (req, res) {

   //the file is uploaded automatically

})
```

EDIT: The above code will upload the **file with hex string as filename without any extension.**

In order to add rename function you need to use `diskStorage`. Here is the code taken from [this github issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/170#issuecomment-123362345) page.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './images/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
      cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + '.' + mime.extension(file.mimetype)); //this is the rename func
    });
  }
});

var uploads = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post('/uploading', uploads.single("file"), function (req, res) {

   //the file is uploaded automatically

})
```

Now you can use the `uploads` variable as middleware as shown in the above snippet.

you can edit the `filename: function (req, file, cb) { .. }` according to your needs. Now the filename will be, *<16characterhexstring>.ext*

Comment: Chakroborty : what is solution of this problem ? How can i upload same image again and again and how we can stop uploading file with image which no need

Comment: The `fs.read` and `fs.write` is creating the additional file. With the above code same image can be uploaded any times. because after each upload the filenames are different a hexadecimal string.

Comment: Can you check it with this code? This is pretty standard and even it's there in the multer docs

Comment: i just checked, same image not uploading but a file is uploading

Comment: Oh ohk, I got your question now. It's expected behaviour. By default multer uploads a file with filename a random string with no extension. You need to add the rename function when uploading. let me add that in the answers.

Comment: @Arita Chakraboty : Now uploading two images, i want to upload just single image which i selected, possible ?

Comment: so, this above piece of code is pretty standard. it uploads single file only. may be there is a problem with other piece of code or the html form. can you check using postman if you are getting expected behavior or not?

Comment: i removed fs.write and fs.read function, now uploading single image as well as same image with again and again , but image saving without original file name, is this possible to save image first time with original name and second time with some other name and so on...?

Comment: That's going to be tricky. Not impossible but then what we can do is in the `filename function` instead of using `crypto` and such we can use `cb(null, file. originalName)` but we need to enclose it with a file exist check. refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648395/upload-a-file-in-nodejs-with-multer-and-change-name-if-the-file-already-exists

Answer (score 0):

another way to handle it will be not using middleware and using multer manually with below options :

```
 try {
        var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function(request, file, callback) {

               //define folder here by fs.mkdirSync(anyDirName);

            },
            filename: function(req, file, callback) {

                callback(null, anyFileName);
            },
            limits: self.limits
        });

        var upload = multer({
            storage: storage,
            fileFilter: function(request, file, callback) {
                // here you can filter out what not to upload..
               } 
        }).any();

        upload(request, response, callback);
    } catch (e) {

    }
```

hope this helps!